# how to find xpath of the input box in the following HTML

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a html like this

```
<td class="random">
  <div id="randomID">Product:</div>
</td>
<td class="random">
  <div id="randomID">
      <input type="text" class="random">
  </div>
</td>
```

my xpath `//div[contains(text(),"Product:")]` gives me the first element for which I want to send input. How do I get the input xpath so I can do input.sendkeys() on it.

Comment: Your question is unclear: what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: I want to find the xpath of input so I can send info via sendkeys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use either of the `xpath` to get the input tag.

Use `following` and index of input tag

```
 //div[contains(text(),"Product:")]/following::input[1]
```

Or find the `td` tag and then use `following-sibling`

```
//td[.//div[contains(text(),"Product:")]]/following-sibling::td[1]//input
```

---

You can use below xpath as well.

```
//div[text()="Product:"]/following::input[1]
```

Or

```
//td[.//div[text()="Product:"]]/following-sibling::td[1]//input
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`following-sibling`**

Try with following xpath:

```
//td[contains(.,"Product:")]//following-sibling::td//input
```

Answer (score 1):

For the provided code, the input is very simple to identify:

```
//input[@class='random']
```

Since I can't see any other duplicate code to force you to be more precise, I don't see the problem in using this one.

If you have multiple , and each or some of them have an input inside, in this case:

```
//div[text()="Product:"]/following::input[1]
```

Where Product is the visible text of the div that you want to use as a parent, and then you go straight in the first input taken by its index.

Comment: `we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/following::input[2]").Attribute("id")` this works for me using Excel VBA and Selenium

Comment: The HTML is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76024245/getting-row-and-column-name-of-a-fillable-box-in-selenium-basic-using-findelemen)