# Getting row and column name of a fillable box in Selenium Basic using FindElementbyXpath()

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium Basic to fill in text to a website from my spreadsheet. The html code of the website is something like this

```
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1" style="width:99%;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" style="font-weight:bold;">FX</th>
            <th scope="col" style="color:White;">Pic</th>
            <th scope="col">Cash</th>
            <th scope="col">Bid</th>
            <th scope="col">Ask</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">
                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl02_Label1">USD1</span>
            </td>
            <td> &nbsp; <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl02_Image1" src="UploadFiles/QLTG-File/MH_200931393922.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp; <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$txtCash" type="text" value="4" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl02_txtCash" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp; <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$txtBid" type="text" value="5" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl02_txtBid" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp; <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl02$txtAsk" type="text" value="6" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl02_txtAsk" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">
                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_Label1">USD2</span>
            </td>
            <td> &nbsp; <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_Image1" src="UploadFiles/QLTG-File/MH_20093139406.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp; <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$txtCash" type="text" value="7" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_txtCash" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp; <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$txtBid" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_txtBid" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp; <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl03$txtAsk" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_txtAsk" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-weight:bold;">
                <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl04_Label1">USD3</span>
            </td>
            <td> &nbsp; <img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl04_Image1" src="UploadFiles/QLTG-File/MH_201441583814.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp; <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl04$txtCash" type="text" value="    " id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl04_txtCash" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp; <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl04$txtBid" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl04_txtBid" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
            <td align="right"> &nbsp; <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1$ctl04$txtAsk" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl04_txtAsk" style="width:100px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to find the row and column name of a fillable box, given this element is got by `fillableBoxes = driver.FindElementsByXPath("//input[@type='text']")`.

I try to get a specific row and column of a fillable box, for example

```
Table = driver.FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1")
Example = Table.FindElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl03_txtBid")
Dim rowElement As WebElement
Set rowElement = Example.FindElementByXPath("./ancestor::tr")
Dim columnHeaderElement As WebElement
Set columnHeaderElement = Example.FindElementByXPath("./ancestor::table/descendant::tr[1]/th[position() = count(./preceding-sibling::td)+1]")

Dim rowName As String
rowName = rowElement.FindElementByXPath("./th").Text
    
Dim columnName As String
columnName = columnHeaderElement.Text
```

The error is

```
NoSuchElementError - Element not found for Xpath=./th
```

and the debug stops at

```
rowName = rowElement.FindElementByXPath("./th").Text
```

It seems I got the XPath wrong. How can I get the right Xpath for getting row and column name?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are likely to be using this code repeatedly, I find it easiest to write a Sub so that use/reuse is easy. In this case, we can write a Sub that takes in the column label, row label, and desired text and sets the desired text in the INPUT found in the cell based on the column and row labels.

```
Sub SetCell(ColLabel As String, RowLabel As String, Text As String)
    ' store the long JS commands to return the indexes
    ColIndexExp = """return document.evaluate(""count(//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1']//th[text()='" & ColLabel & "']/preceding::th) + 1"", document, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null).numberValue"""
    RowIndexExp = """return document.evaluate(""count(//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1']//tr[./td/span[text()='" & RowLabel & "']]/preceding::tr) + 1"",  document, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null).numberValue"""
    ' execute the JS commands and store the values
    ColIndex = ExecuteScript(ColIndexExp)
    RowIndex = ExecuteScript(RowIndexExp)
    ' print the values to the console for debugging, can be safely removed
    Debug.Print ColIndex
    Debug.Print RowIndex
    ' set the desired text in the appropriate cell based on the labels provided
    driver.FindElementByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1']//tr[" & RowIndex & "]/td[" & ColIndex & "]/input").SendKeys (Text)
End Sub
```

Then call it like

```
SetCell "Bid", "USD1", "ABCD"
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me in Excel, VBA and SeleniumBasic with Edge browser.
Each of the commented out lines works and shows how I built up
the final XPath to pick out a specific `INPUT` box in the `TABLE` html.
I wrote out the resulting html as a text file as it is always useful to
use a text editor to understand what is going on with the html selected.
The final piece of XPath picks out the Id of the second input field of
the second row - a Cash field.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sbXPathTableInput()
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim we As WebElement
    sURL = "https://davetallett26.github.io/table.html"
    Dim sFilename As String
    Call driver.Start("edge", sURL)
    driver.get (sURL)
    driver.Window.Maximize
    sbDelay (100000)
    Set we = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body")
    sFilename = "C:\Users\david\Downloads\out-" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddHHMMSS") & ".txt"
    Open sFilename For Output As #1
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("//input").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/following::input[1]").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/following::input[1]").Attribute("name")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/following::input[1]").Attribute("id")
    ' second row, second input field
    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/following::input[2]").Attribute("id")  
    Close #1
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.Quit
End Sub

Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay:  DoEvents: Next i: End Sub 'old skool delay
```